# Using PHP's modulus to dump dataset every nth iteration

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
$numbers=array (
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '10',
  '11',
);

$output = array();

foreach($numbers as $i=>$number)
{
    $output[]= $number;

    if(($i+1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        var_dump($output);
        $output=array();
    }
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
```

I've been banging my head to also dump the remainder, something like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "10"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "11"
}
```

I know there's a way to do this using the modulus operator, I saw it an a snippet a few months ago but now I can't find it. I think they were using subtraction in the modulus line.

If it helps, the var_dump will be replaced by an insert statement to mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `array_chunk()` ?

Comment: after your `foreach {}` just `var_dump($output);` one last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option: count the array beforehand, and check in your loop if you're at the end.

```
$last_key = count($numbers) -1;
$output = array();

foreach($numbers as $i=>$number)
{
    $output[]= $number;

    if(($i+1) % 3 == 0 || $i == $last_key && $output)
    {
        var_dump($output);
        $output=array();
    }
}
```

I like doing it this way because you don't have to repeat the code from your loop after it ends.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need another calculation, just var_dump after the loop and clear your output array if you want it to end up empty.

```
$numbers=array (
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
);

$output = array();
foreach($numbers as $i=>$number)
{
    $output[]= $number;
    if(($i+1) % 3 == 0){
        var_dump($output);
        $output = array();
    }
}

if($output) var_dump($output); //outputs remainder
$output = array(); //optional final clear.
```

Comment: Maybe `if ($output) var_dump($output);` so you won't get a blank one if it happens to divide evenly.

Comment: edited, in most cases I keep it as simple as it needs to be.

Comment: Understandable; I wasn't necessarily suggesting an edit. Just an FYI for whoever happened to look at it.

Answer (score -3):

why dont you count?

```
$i=0;
foreach($numbers as $key=>$number)
{
    $output[]= $number;

    if(($i+1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        var_dump($output);
        $output=array();
    }
    $i++;
}
```

or use $number directly.

Comment: this does not answer the OPs question at all